# Как вывести из поля несколько значений?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица mysql, в ней есть в поле img. В нем содержатся несколько фотографий, в одном поле может быть несколько фоток вот так:

```
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1JvMFoILJ8KJjy0Fnq6AFDpXaz/-.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1IT2ooRDH8KJjSspnq6zNAVXa0/-.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1RH2YoJnJ8KJjSszdq6yxuFXaJ/-.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1vcxDfYorBKNjSZFjq6A_SpXaL/-.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ljqVrHSYBuNjSspiq6xNzpXaP/-.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10kV0f_qWBKNjSZFxq6ApLpXaR/-.jpg' ,
```

Как мне на php вывести все фотографии в виде ,  и т.д.? Или это нереально?

Comment: Нужно вывести списком все фото из этого поля.

Comment: `explode(',', $field);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выводиш  все фотографии на одно переменное скажем $a потом зделаеш так

```
$b=explode(',', $a);
foreach($b as $item){
echo $item;//здесь выводит каждый отдельно можеш ешо вставить здесь свой логику
}
```

Comment: Удалились запятые, остались одинарные кавычки.

Comment: @StopTussin чтобы убрать кавычки используй функцию rtrim($item, "'")